# To change the value of parameter in CGridView using Yii

Tags: php, yii

I a have a basic question about CGridViews. I have the table employees stored in my DB and I am showing some of his atributs using this CGridView. The problem is that I stored all the passwords using the md5 codification, and when I want to show them I don't know how to show them without the md5 codification.

I tried it with the sentence: "'password'=>$dataProvider->employee->md5(password)," But as you can imagine it is wrong and it doesn't work. This is my CGridView with parameter password changed to this sentence.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
 'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'id'=>'employee_list',
 'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'name',
            //'password',
    'password'=>$dataProvider->employee->md5(password),
        array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

Somebody could help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks like you are missing important information about what MD5 (and in general, any [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)) is. One of their properties is that they are not reversible. You cannot ever get the original password out of its MD5 hash. If you could, what would be the purpose of hashing it?

Comment: I agree with you Jon, I missed it....SORRY! Even so, I have the same question. Forgetting the md5 funcion, I mean, if I want to change the value of the password to in whatever another value (not to decode the real password value) and to show it, what I should to do? THANKS

Comment: If you just want to change the value of the password to another value, why not just simply encode it again with whatever method you like? Sha, Base64 or even md5(again)

Comment: He n3ISe, yes, you are right, but now my question is about HOW to change this value to whatever vaule, I mean, I don't know where to write to change this value hehe. It is a theoretical question. Thanks n3ISe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to pass php code as string, Cgridview will run that string with eval function,
Please refer following code for more clarification:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
            array(
                    'name'=>'password',
                    'value'=>'md5($data->password)',
            ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Hello sarvesh, thanks, your code help me a lot to understand how to change the values of the parameters in a CGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you encoded your password with `base64_encode($password)` then what you have to do is `base64_decode($encoded_password)`

from your question, is it `$dataProvider->md5(password)`?

maybe you can refer the code below.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'leaveapplication-grid1',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->searchpersonalleave($myid),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(

        'leave_dateapplied',
        'leave_id',
        array('name'=>'leave_category','value'=>'$data->getcategoryname($data->leave_category)' ), //0-annual, 1-medical, 2-emergency
        'leave_startdate',
        //'leave_enddate',
        'leave_duration',
        'leave_reason',

        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}{update}',
            'buttons'=>array
                    (
                'update' => array
                        (
                    'visible'=>'($data->getupdatefunction(17) =="Yes")',
                       ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: n3ISe thank you very much. About the enconde, I wanted to use md5, don't worry. Now I know how to change the value of a parameter. My problem is that I never understand the difference between $data, $this, and $dataProvider, so it usual that I am confuses many times.